# Is it possible record traffic from mobile device without WiFi

Tags: jmeter, monitoring, load-testing, mobile-application

I try to use JMeter for mobile applications load testing.

But its not comfartable to use WiFi every time when I need to record Mobile app traffic.

Is it possible to use USB cable to record traffic from mobile device to computer?

For example create 2 line Proxy: Mobile Device(Mob app) → Computer (JMeter) Proxy → Mobile Device Proxy → Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use some form of the [reverse USB tethering](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/how-to-set-up-reverse-tethering-over-usb) it means that your mobile device is basically using your computer network interface to access the outside world (intra or internet). So you need to record your PC, not your mobile traffic, to wit treat your mobile device as normal desktop application which is communicating with the backend.

In this setup you need to configure your whole operating system to use JMeter as the proxy so the traffic would be intercepted by JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder). The setup is different basing on the operating system of the computer, check out How to [Run Performance Tests of Desktop Applications Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter) article to get the overall idea regarding what needs to be done in order to record the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible provided you have access from device to server.

You would be using the localhost/8888 or machine IP / 8888 as a proxy.